# How to make this MongoDB aggregation return key:value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregation:

```
$out = $db->stats->aggregate (
        array('$match' => $where),
        ,array( '$group' => 
            array( "_id" => '$traffic.source', 
                    'count'=> array('$sum' => 1)
            )
        )
        ,array( '$project' => 
            array( "_id" => 0, 
                'type' => '$_id',
                'count' => '$count'
            )
        )
    );
```

which returns an array with:

```
[{type:sourceA, count:2},{type:sourceB, count:6}...]
```

Is it possible to make it return:
`[sourceA:2, sourceB:6,....]`  without looping the array afterwords?

Comment: Have you tried array( "_id" => 0, '$_id' => '$count') ?

Comment: it's not possible without looping and even with looping, it's only possible if you know all values of "type".